# Extrude edge using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural

[image]Version: Blender 3.3

**Goal**: use geometry nodes to create a roof rafter system that will align the three boards that form the rafter triangle align properly (hypotenuse board sits on corners of horizontal and vertical boards) given any length of the horizontal and vertical boards.

**Current approach**: Use ray cast of joined geometry of the horizontal and vertical boards to add a mesh line to connect the corners of the H&V boards - creating a hypotenuse line. I then extrude the edge of the mesh line twice to form a cube for the horizontal board.

**Problems**:

1. the hypotenuse "cube" extruded edge does not follow the desired direction - i.e. it does not rest upon the horizontal/vertical edge in the depth direction, this appears to be the result of the first instance of the edge extrustion as it goes off at about an 11 degree angle from straight from the z direction.
2. the horizontal board in not cubic shaped but rhombozoidanl.

I thought about using a cube instead of a mesh line - but don't know how to do that using a ray cast to determine dim of cube.

Also tried using instant on point w/end point selection to place new cube on raycast mesh line - my new cube disappear when I attach endpoint node to instant on point node.

[node tree all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiuDF.png)
[image: sub node tree - horz and vert boards]
[image: sub tree horz & vert boards]
[image: sub tree right side hypotenuse board]

Comment: I think it would be extremely helpful in answering your question if you could clarify this with pictures and/or share your blend file with us: https://www.blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I believe I uploaded my file to stack exchange but not sure at this time how to verify it is there and linked to this question.

Comment: When you upload the file to https://www.blend-exchange.com/, a link will be displayed after a successful upload. You have to copy this link and paste it into the question. If you don't have the link anymore, you have to repeat the process.

Comment: how long it take to process after an upload....been waiting for few hours, no link appears on stack exchange.

Comment: You don't want a mitre? You want the boards in contact only at the corners? If not, do you need a ridge board?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/277273/extrude-edge-using-geometry-nodes

Comment: Just want to work out the concept of doing this in nodes at this point. Mitre will probably  be an option I would build into final node tree. Seems like this is very basic but I haven't found a straightforward approach without using multiple trigonometry nodes to keep angles correct.

Comment: Project, I am using this for circ 1900 gambrel style barn. I believe most had ridge board. so probably mitre solution is needed. I not an architect so I am only going off old photo's.